# Java IndexOutOfBoundsException in Arraylist

Tags: arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

Below is the code that I wrote:

```
    import static java.lang.System.out;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    class Uni{
        static public void main(String...args){
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            ArrayList<Integer>list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int a=0,i=0;list.get(i)!=42;i++){    
                  a=sc.nextInt();
                  list.add(i,a);
            }
            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
                out.println(list.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the error im getting:

> Execution failed.
>       java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException : Index: 0, Size: 0
>
> ```
> Stack Trace:
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
> at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
> at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
> at Uni.main(Uni.java:8)
> ```

Can you please help with what to do?

Comment: Use debugger and it will obvious.

Comment: What are you expecting `list.get(i)!=42` to do when the list is empty?

Comment: your list is empty, also you must use try-catch while iterating such lists and list starts from 1 not 0.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you wanted to use a while cycle? It's much easier to initialize the list.
Furthermore, your code is checking if `list.get(i)` is not equal to 42, but you cannot do that because your list at the index 0 is still null.

A solution could be:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
class Uni{
    static public void main(String...args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer>list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int i = 0;
        while(i!=42) {
            list.add(i++,sc.nextInt());
        }
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            out.println(list.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: to stop after the Input is 42:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
class Uni{
    static public void main(String...args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer>list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int i = 0
        while (true) {
            int in = sc.nextInt();
            if (in==42) break;
            list.add(i++,sc.nextInt())
         }

        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            out.println(list.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to stop taking input when the one of the inputs become 42 thats why I used list.get(i) != 42. Can you help me with that?